# How would I remove all spaces between single quotes skipping escaped quotes in PHP

Tags: php, parsing

Exactly as the title asks:

How would I remove all unnecessary spaces between single quotes skipping escaped quotes in PHP?

I am looking for a fast implementation to pre-prep for parsing.  I would prefer not to use regex if it would be slower than using a simple loop.

(The double quotes below are for display purposes only)

examples would be:

input:

```
"    testing    '  this  is a     \'test\'  '     zzz     "
```

output:

```
"testing '  this  is a     \'test\'  ' zzz"
```

Comment: Your example doesn't seem very clear. It looks like you want to strip excess spaces that are ... between double-quotes but not single-quotes?

Comment: You're correct, I will edit my posting.  Ty.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$parts = preg_split('/((?<!\\\\)|(?<=\\\\\\\\))\'/', trim($data));

foreach ($parts as $index => &$part) {
    if ($index % 2 == 0) {
        $part = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $part);
    }
}

echo join('\'', $parts);
```

Now to wait for the much simpler solution I've missed :p

Comment: How does this handle a string containing `\\'`? Given that the apostrophe isn't escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, psuedocode time:

```
var shouldtrim = true;
var escaped = false;
foreach char in string
    if char is whitespace and lastchar is whitespace and shouldtrim
        remove char from string

    if char is ' and not escaped
        toggle shouldtrim

    if char is \
        toggle escaped
    else
        escaped = false
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$str = "    testing    '  this  is a     \'test\'  '     zzz     ";

echo trim($str," ");

?>
```

Comment: That will remove spaces inside single quotes.  Not what I am looking for.